# dojo/subscribe does not work if the document is not ready

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a small requirement. We have a application controller and a custom dijit which work together with each other.

I want to publish a event from the dijit and subscribe the same in controller.  But the problem is the controller is not loaded first time when publish event is triggered, so the subscribe is not working first time.

Once the controller is loaded, if we publish again, then subscribe works perfectly fine.

Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: This is going to sound blunt, but the solution is to make sure you subscribe before the topic is published.  It sounds like that would require some reorganization within your app.  Without specifics, this question is too broad to answer in a way that is likely to be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dojo/ready to make sure, all necessary Parts are loaded? Check your loading hierarchy. Is it possible to load the controller in the init-phase at the start?

Regard

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers Dimitri and Ken Franqueiro & MiBrock.  Dimitri's solution sound useful to me.  The controller and the Widget which publish the event are not on same page also the controlller is not always loaded whereas the Widget is part of my Menu so its present on every page.

What I tried is used Memory to pass the data and first time called the function where the event and data will be used.  So my widget sets data in Memory store and in controller, once its loaded we retrieve the value and use it.  So this happens only first time, from second time onwards my published calls are working as Controller is loaded on page.